# Attach route as a prefix to the website name

Tags: node.js, routes, web-development-server

I am developing a Node Js app at the moment. My routes look like this: domainname.com/route. However, I would like some of my routes to look like this: route.domainname.com or route-domainname.com. If you have done something like that before, could you please point me in the right direction because I don't even know what to search for in Google.

Comment: Check for A records and CNAME of domains

Comment: @Vipulw I don't think that's what I need. I want to create route for the admin dashboard, which will look like admin.domainname.com or admin-domainname.com. I am not looking to redirect to another site.